# Error inflating class mapbox MapView - with minifyEnabled

Tags: android, mapbox

I've implemented mapbox correctly before using android sdk 28 to compile, now mapbox crash only in release mode because I've minifyEnabled true. If I set it to false, doesn't crash.
The Exception is

```
Binary XML Error inflating com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.
```

I use mapbox on fragment, and call

```
Mapbox.getInstance(getContext(), "TOKEN")
```

before inflating view in onCreateView method. Even after, same problem.

I think is a gradle problem, that is

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
signingConfigs {
    debug {
        keyAlias 'ewhfpiqwufgqeifbqeifb'
        keyPassword 'dbhedeiqlgdqoiefqwouf'
    }
    release {

    }
}
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "widjpewoqhfqiwfhuw"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 65
    versionName "1.1.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        useProguard false
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        ext.enableCrashlytics = true
    }
}

flavorDimensions "release", "debug"

productFlavors {
    debugFlavor {
        dimension "debug"
    }
    releaseFlavor {
        dimension "release"
        applicationIdSuffix ""
        versionNameSuffix ""
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation ('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.3.0'){
        transitive=true
    }
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.2'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Other info on crash:

```
Exception in onDidFinishLoadingStyle
java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
Abort message: 'terminating with uncaught exception of type 
jni::PendingJavaException'
/data/app/mypkg- 
qtZprFdEiYN4aOjj_lCtiA==/lib/arm64/libmapbox-gl.so
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set minifyEnabled true, it will Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization which remove unused classes.

Use proguard to solve this:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/master/MapboxAndroidDemo/proguard-rules.pro

Comment: yeah, I was trying this. For others, the solution for me i enable proguard and add                   -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod